How to Make Headers Vertical in Telerik WPF Data Grid?
I am working on a WPF application using Telerik's RadGridView, and I would like to change the orientation of the column headers to be vertical instead of the default horizontal. So, What I mean is that I don't want the header text to be vertical. But, Instead the headers must be present in the column 0 (one below the other instead of side by side).
I know few ways how you can set the headers vertically. But the problem is that if i set the headers row wise, I don't know how many data will be there. So, to make things clear, the column size is fixed. But the row size is not.
The Other approach would be not to use to telerik. But, instead implementing wpf natively. Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
